# How do I change the select option from the component in Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-material2

I have a dropdown like below

html

```
<mat-form-field>
  <mat-select placeholder="Team" [(ngModel)]="selectedTeam" name="team"
              (change)="mainValuesChanged('team',$event,t.value)" #t>
      <mat-option *ngFor="let team of teams" [value]="team.value"  >
      {{ team.viewValue }}
      </mat-option>
  </mat-select>
</mat-form-field>
```

ts

```
selectedTeam="team1"
teams = {"value":"t1","viewValue":"team1",
         "value":"t2","viewValue":"team2",
         "value":"newTeam",""viewValue":"Create Team"}
```

What I'd like to do is when the user clicks on 'Create Team' the previous values(t1:team1 or t2:team2) remain same, while I create a new team by form, etc.

How do I get reference to the select element so that I can change [value] to the previous value?

So far I have this:

```
mainValuesChanged(term,event:MatSelectChange,tValue){
    if (event.value==="newTeam"){
        this.selectedTeam = getPrevTeamNamefromAService();
        #hack, hack 
    }
}
```

If I could only reference the select element and set the [value] to selectedTeam or just change the selected value from the component without a direct reference, I would be able to do this. How do I achieve this?

Comment: why not create a button that handles this create functionality on its own rather than incorporating it into the select

Answer (score 0):

If you take a look at the [API docs for the select](https://material.angular.io/components/select/api), you can see that MatSelect is exported as `matSelect`. This means that you can get a reference to the select in the template by writing `#t="matSelect"`. If you then pass this `#t` into your function, you can update the select's value like this:

```
mainValuesChanged(term, event:MatSelectChange, select: MatSelect){
    if (event.value==="newTeam"){
        select.writeValue(getPrevTeamNamefromAService());
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.